# PayPal permissions required to setup subscriptions?

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I've been given developer access to a clients paypal account , but when creating a subscription (specifically the first step, creating a "product") I'm getting "Your account access is limited. Contact the account owner to get necessary permissions."

On this page https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/sell/permissions-outside, it lists   a bunch of permissions. The only ones that seem at all relevant are "Activate and authorize APIs" , "Discuss account with Customer Service" and potentially "Schedule recurring payments.

I'd like to get back to the client with a comprehensive list of everything I'll need.

If anyone has been through this process before, are those the right ones? Are there other ones I'm likely to need?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two permissions when managing the user https://www.paypal.com/businessmanage/users

- Access APIs and developer support site
- Set up automated payments

You should be able to access https://www.paypal.com/billing/plans to create a product with that, or https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications to do so with the API.

Comment: Than's so much, I really appreciate the detailed hyper-linked response, couldn't ask for more.